# How can I crop an image to the shape of a svg/png mask in scala/java

Tags: java, scala, awt

Say I have a Z shaped white mask and I want to crop an image to this shape. How can I do this in java?

Both images are 2560x1440, but the Z shaped mask has transparent bits.

My attempt in scala but using Java's awt library:

```
val imageBuff = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
val imageB = imageBuff.createGraphics()
imageB.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null)

val maskBuffered = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
val maskB = mask01Buffered.createGraphics()
maskB.drawImage(scaledmask, 0, 0, null)


def applyMask(imageBuffered: BufferedImage, maskBuffered: BufferedImage): BufferedImage = {
  val imagePixels = heroBuffered.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width)
  val maskPixels = maskBuffered.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width)

 for (i <- 0 to maskPixels.length - 1)
  {
    val color = imagePixels(i)
    val mask = maskPixels(i) 
    imagePixels(i) = mask | color
  }

  imageBuffered.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, imagePixels, 0, width)
  imageBuffered
}

val maskApplied = applyMask(imageBuff, maskBuffered)

val scaledForeground: Image = maskApplied.getScaledInstance((width * 1.08).toInt, (height * 1.08).toInt, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)

val finalImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
val f = finalImage.createGraphics
val newX: Int = (0 - width * 0.08).toInt
val newY: Int = (0 - height * 0.08).toInt
f.drawImage(scaledForeground, newX, newY, null)

ImageIO.write(finalImage, "jpeg", new FileOutputStream(imagePath.takeWhile(_.toString != ".") + "-" + keyline.name + "-final-image.jpeg"))
f.dispose()
```

This creates an image where I get the original image showing through a very small part of the z shape, but I want to strip away anything where the mask is transparent.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Many thanks, J

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out. The trick was in the for loop.

It needed to be more like this:

```
for (i <- 0 to heroPixels.length - 1)
  {
    val color = heroPixels(i)
    val mask = maskPixels(i)

    if (mask == whiteInt) {
      heroPixels(i) = color
    } else
      heroPixels(i) = new Color(0,0,0, 1).getRGB
  }
```

And then using `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` rather than `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB`